# How can I make a list of quotes?

Tags: support, markdown

I was trying to make a list of example sentences that should better written in a comment, rather than writing then in the question.

I have tried with the following Markdown, but the result was not the expected one.

```
- 
> I have looked for a similar question, but I could not find it. If this is a duplicate, feel free to delete it.

- 
> This question is not a duplicate of that question; they are similar, but I have different requirements.

-
> @Downvoters: Is this question so bad?
```

The text is rendered as follows.

- > I have looked for a similar question, but I could not find it. If this is a duplicate, feel free to delete it.
- > This question is not a duplicate of that question; they are similar, but I have different requirements.

-

> @Downvoters: Is this question so bad?

The first two points are rendered correctly, but the third one is not rendered in the same way.

If I don't write the > character in a new line, the following text is not quoted.

- > First point.
- > Second point.

Is there a way to make a list of quotes that is rendered as I am expecting, or should I just avoid to make a list, and put `<!-- break -->` between the quotes?

Comment: The third looks like this because you don't have a space after the `-` character (newline !== space). Adding a space made it look like the other two..

Comment: Whoops, you are right. May you post it as answer? `:)`

Comment: [Done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135673/152859)! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were missing a mere blank space.

In the third list item you don't have a space after the `-` character (keep in mind that newline !== space).

Adding a space made it look like the other two in the preview and "solve" this issue. :)

Comment: Ah +1. I didn't spot that. :)

Answer (score 7):

- > This seems to work
- > just fine for me
- > @kiamlaluno: Would you agree?

Or am I missing the point?

FYI, the markdown looks like this:

```
-   > This seems to work

-   > just fine for me

-   > @kiamlaluno: Would you agree?
```

Comment: I have tried adding more spaces, but I didn't add an empty line between the list items.